# Render shows no image, just a color screen

Tags: rendering

[image: Cycle render]

I am trying to make a wallpaper 2560x1440, but in the render result I can't see anything, just color as shown in the screenshot.

That is the .blend

[image]

Comment: please upload the .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: how can upload it. thx for care :)

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: i did it brother :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were two reasons.

1. you had no light in the scene. (I just added a sunlight)
2. You had your camera aperture set to .2 ( I just disabled DOF) [image]